# Cannot deserialize RDD with different number of items in pair

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, rdd

I have two RDD's which have key-value pairs. I want to join them by key (and according to the key, get cartesian product of all values), which I assume can be done with zip() function of pyspark. However, when I apply this,

```
elemPairs = elems1.zip(elems2).reduceByKey(add)
```

It gives me the error:

```
Cannot deserialize RDD with different number of items in pair: (40, 10)
```

And here are the 2 RDD's which I try to zip:

```
elems1 => [((0, 0), ('A', 0, 90)), ((0, 1), ('A', 0, 90)), ((0, 2), ('A', 0, 90)), ((0, 3), ('A', 0, 90)), ((0, 4), ('A', 0, 90)), ((0, 0), ('A', 1, 401)), ((0, 1), ('A', 1, 401)), ((0, 2), ('A', 1, 401)), ((0, 3), ('A', 1, 401)), ((0, 4), ('A', 1, 401)), ((1, 0), ('A', 0, 305)), ((1, 1), ('A', 0, 305)), ((1, 2), ('A', 0, 305)), ((1, 3), ('A', 0, 305)), ((1, 4), ('A', 0, 305)), ((1, 0), ('A', 1, 351)), ((1, 1), ('A', 1, 351)), ((1, 2), ('A', 1, 351)), ((1, 3), ('A', 1, 351)), ((1, 4), ('A', 1, 351)), ((2, 0), ('A', 0, 178)), ((2, 1), ('A', 0, 178)), ((2, 2), ('A', 0, 178)), ((2, 3), ('A', 0, 178)), ((2, 4), ('A', 0, 178)), ((2, 0), ('A', 1, 692)), ((2, 1), ('A', 1, 692)), ((2, 2), ('A', 1, 692)), ((2, 3), ('A', 1, 692)), ((2, 4), ('A', 1, 692)), ((3, 0), ('A', 0, 936)), ((3, 1), ('A', 0, 936)), ((3, 2), ('A', 0, 936)), ((3, 3), ('A', 0, 936)), ((3, 4), ('A', 0, 936)), ((3, 0), ('A', 1, 149)), ((3, 1), ('A', 1, 149)), ((3, 2), ('A', 1, 149)), ((3, 3), ('A', 1, 149)), ((3, 4), ('A', 1, 149))]

elems2 => [((0, 0), ('B', 0, 573)), ((1, 0), ('B', 0, 573)), ((2, 0), ('B', 0, 573)), ((3, 0), ('B', 0, 573)), ((4, 0), ('B', 0, 573)), ((0, 0), ('B', 1, 324)), ((1, 0), ('B', 1, 324)), ((2, 0), ('B', 1, 324)), ((3, 0), ('B', 1, 324)), ((4, 0), ('B', 1, 324))]
```

Where `((0, 0), ('B', 0, 573)), (0, 0)` is the key and `('B', 0, 573)` is the value.

After a quick google search, I found that it is a problem which only occurs in spark 1.2, however I have used Spark 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use elems1.join(elems2)

Comment: Looks like it is what I need. Let me check. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The reason of that error message is described in the [RDD API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

> Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the first element in each RDD, second element in each RDD, etc. Assumes that the two RDDs have the *same number of partitions* and the *same number of elements in each partition* (e.g. one was made through a map on the other).

As @alwaysprep said, you could use `join`, as `zip` does something completely different:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(1 to 100, 3)
val b = sc.parallelize(101 to 200, 3)
a.zip(b).collect
res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,101), (2,102), (3,103), (4,104), (5,105), 
(6,106), (7,107), (8,108), (9,109), (10,110), (11,111), (12,112), (13,113), 
(14,114), (15,115), (16,116), (17,117), (18,118), (19,119), (20,120), (21,121), 
(22,122), (23,123), (24,124), (25,125), (26,126), (27,127), (28,128), (29,129), 
(30,130), (31,131), (32,132), (33,133), (34,134), (35,135), (36,136), (37,137), 
(38,138), (39,139), (40,140), (41,141), (42,142), (43,143), (44,144), (45,145), 
(46,146), (47,147), (48,148), (49,149), (50,150), (51,151), (52,152), (53,153), 
(54,154), (55,155), (56,156), (57,157), (58,158), (59,159), (60,160), (61,161), 
(62,162), (63,163), (64,164), (65,165), (66,166), (67,167), (68,168), (69,169), 
(70,170), (71,171), (72,172), (73,173), (74,174), (75,175), (76,176), (77,177), 
(78,...
```

As you can see, zip associates the n-th element of array `a` to the n-th element of array `b`, hence the arrays must have the same size.

In your case, array `elem1` contains more elements than `elem2` - maybe you can have a look at `rightOuterJoin` (or `leftOuterJoin`). This is due to the fact that .join is going to skip those elements without key in both the RDDs. For example, I see that (4,0) is only present in `elem2`. If you `join` them, then it will be skipped, as it won't be found in the `elem1` array. Additionally, there is the method `.cartesian`, if you really want the cartesian product.