# Pyspark rdd.zip ValueError: Can not deserialize RDD with different number of items in pair

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using spark 1.6.0 and I have a pyspark.mllib.tree.RandomForestModel for a prediction task. My data_rdd is formatted as follows:

```
[LabeledPoint(id1,feature),
 LabeledPoint(id2,feature),
...]
```

My code is

```
rfmodel = RandomForestModel.load(sc,modelpath)
```

What I want is to get ids along with predicted labels. So I do the followings,

```
predictions = rfmodel.predict(data_rdd.map(lambda x:x.features))
idsAndPredictions = data_rdd.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
```

I run this code and it gives an error

```
ValueError: Can not deserialize RDD with different number of items in pair: (91, 90)
```

The error happens because of the zip function. It seems people get this error for not having data_rdd and predictions of the same length. But in my case, data_rdd and predictions obviously have the same length.

My question is how to get this working and if it's a spark bug, is there any other way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: Can you please provide the length of the predictions and data_rdd.map(lambda lp: lp.label) because from the code it seems they are of different length

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava Thank you for your reply. In my case, predictions comes from a row by row map operation from data_rdd. So I don't think they are of different length. My data consists of hundreds of million samples so it may take a while to count them respectively. Sure I'll consider this possibility and provide the count number later. Thank you again for your advice.

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176526/cannot-deserialize-rdd-with-different-number-of-items-in-pair)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I make it work by reduce the number of partitions from around 500000 by default to 500. I hope someone could enlighten me.